# Сбор статистики MTProto Proxy

Tags: linux, debian, docker, telegram, mtproto

Взял чистую VPS на Debian 9. Docker CE установлен по [официальному мануалу](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/debian/). MTProto proxy тоже установлен [также](https://hub.docker.com/r/telegrammessenger/proxy/).

Пытаюсь получить доступ к статистике, но не выходит:

```
root@v127299:~#  docker exec mtproto-proxy curl http://localhost:2398/stats
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                               Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 2398: Connection refused
root@v127299:~#
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[введите сюда описание ссылки](https://codeby.net/threads/razvjortyvanie-svoego-)

-mtproxy-telegram-so-statistikoj.67936/

Comment: https://codeby.net/threads/razvjortyvanie-svoego-mtproxy-telegram-so-statistikoj.67936/

Comment: Убери скриншот и напиши своими словами.

Comment: Статья помогла. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Предположим, что MTProxy запущен с помощью `docker compose` с таким конфигурационным файлом:

```yml
version: '2.4'

services:
  tgproxy:
    image: telegrammessenger/proxy:1.4
    volumes:
      - ./proxy-config:/data
    ports:
      - 0.0.0.0:443:443
    restart: unless-stopped
```

После запуска контейнера "как есть" эндпоинт `localhost:2398/stats` не отвечает:

```sh
$ docker compose up -d tgproxy
# запускаем docker-compose сервис

[+] Running 1/2
 ⠸ Network tgproxy_default  Created                0.4s
 ✔ Container tgproxy        Started                0.4s

$ docker compose ps tgproxy
# проверяем что он запустился и работает

NAME      IMAGE                         COMMAND                  SERVICE   CREATED          STATUS          PORTS
tgproxy   telegrammessenger/proxy:1.4   "/bin/sh -c '/bin/ba…"   tgproxy   11 seconds ago   Up 10 seconds   0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp

$ docker compose exec tgproxy curl -4sS http://localhost:2398/stats
# пытаемся обратиться к эндпоинту localhost:2398/stats и получаем ошибку

curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 2398: Connection refused
```

Причина - в недостающем ключе `--http-stats` в вызове `mtproto-proxy` на последней строчке скрипта `/run.sh` внутри контейнера:

```bash
$ docker compose exec tgproxy tail -n1 -- /run.sh \
      exec /usr/local/bin/mtproto-proxy -p 2398 -H 443 -M "$WORKERS" \
      -C 60000 --aes-pwd /etc/telegram/hello-explorers-how-are-you-doing \
      -u root $CONFIG --allow-skip-dh \
      --nat-info "$INTERNAL_IP:$IP" $SECRET_CMD $TAG_CMD
```

Исправим это:

```bash
$ docker compose exec tgproxy sed -E -i \
      -- "/--http-stats/! s#(/usr/local/bin/mtproto-proxy)#\1 --http-stats#" /run.sh
# эта команда ничего не выводит, выполняется молча

$ docker compose exec tgproxy tail -n1 -- /run.sh
# можно увидеть, что недостающий ключ --http-stats добавился к вызову mtproto-proxy

exec /usr/local/bin/mtproto-proxy --http-stats -p 2398 -H 443 -M "$WORKERS" \
    -C 60000 --aes-pwd /etc/telegram/hello-explorers-how-are-you-doing \
    -u root $CONFIG --allow-skip-dh --nat-info "$INTERNAL_IP:$IP" $SECRET_CMD $TAG_CMD

$ docker compose exec tgproxy curl -4sS http://localhost:2398/stats
# но эндпоинт localhost:2398/stats всё равно не отвечает, т.к. мы отредактировали скрипт, 
# а mtproto-proxy не перезапустили

curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 2398: Connection refused

$ docker compose exec tgproxy pkill -9 mtproto-proxy
# убиваем 1 из mtproto-proxy, это вызовет автоматический рестарт контейнера

$ docker compose exec tgproxy curl -4sS http://localhost:2398/stats
# теперь эндпоинт localhost:2398/stats отвечает

pid     7
start_time      1709043377
current_time    1709043378
uptime  1
tot_idle_time   1.454
...
```

Данный способ устраняет проблему на время существования контейнера. Если контейнер будет уничтожен и пересоздан (`docker compose down && docker compose up -d`), фикс придётся применить заново.